# Question on force and friction (beginner level)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

Please read this question thoroghly. I just want to clear my conception. Suppose I have a mass $M_1$ and another mass $M_2$ on top of $M_1$. Now if I pull M<sub>1</sub> with force F ,******the whole system should get acceleration a ,where a =F/(M<sub>1</sub>+M<sub>2</sub>) .I added two masses because mass is an inherent quality that oppose change in velocity and  both masses here are connected I should add them in order to find acceleration.******Now most important note - there is no friction between M1 and plane and no friction between M1 and M2 . so without friction between M1 and M2 can I say M1 and M2 aren't connected ?so the correct equation should be a=F/m1 ? Is this explanation correct ?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: @Ben51 ok thanks

Comment: ... but note that, without friction, $M_1$ accelerates but $M_2$ stays still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the two masses aren't connected via friction or using another medium (such as a lead or a spring), hence you can't consider the two masses as a unique mass (or as a system of connected body). Every mass has to be considered separate from the other ones. So the equation that holds for this situation is, as you wrote: $$\vec{F} = M_1 \vec{a}$$ which you can break down on each direction considering the verse and direction of the reference sistem: $$ F_x = M_1 a_x $$ $$ F_y = M_1 a_y $$ as I deduce, the force is exerted on a single direction, which coincides with an axe and it agrees with its verse, so, it returns $$ F = ma $$
The other equation you were talking about, as I said before, holds iff the two masses can be considered as a system of connected body. In this second case one would have: $$ \vec{F} = (M_1 + M_2) \vec{a} $$ which can be decomposed along the axis of the reference frame (considering the verse of this axis): $$ F_x = (M_1 + M_2) a_x $$ $$ F_y = (M_1 + M_2) a_y $$
Nevertheless, one has to notice that two masses can hardly considered a unique connected body if one is on the top of the other. This because, for the inertia principle (I principle of dinamics) a body that is in motion or in rest tends to stay in that status. Indeed the upper body tends to stay in rest while the lower one it is pushed. This two masses can move together only for acceleration levels under a certain value whose corresponding force added to the friction between the two masses generates a total force very similiar and almost equal to the total force on the lower mass.

Hope I have been useful! If yes, please, help me grow on this platform by rating my answer